# CSS, selecting with specific Classes and types

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm not expert with CSS, and I would like to select starting from the `id` without using JavaScript

Unfortunately **the HTML code is autogenerated**, I can't set some defined class...

Select `id="main"` -> `class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit ui-footer-fixed slideup"` -> (`select fisrt Div`) -> (`select first UL`) -> (`select class="ui-block-a"`) -> (`select a`)

Here my HTML code, what would I fill in where I have ??? in the style?

```css
#main>??? {
  /*my CSS Code*/
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-url="..." data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-footer-fixed ui-page-active" style="padding-top: 42px; padding-bottom: 35px; min-height: 735px;">
  <div data-id="navHeaderDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1 id="cxpTitleH1" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div class="voOutput" id="titlePrompt" />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="groupDiv" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-first-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Misin">Misión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Visin">Visión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-last-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_NuestrasSedes">Nuestras Sedes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="navFooterDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo" class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit ui-footer-fixed slideup">
    <div data-iconpos="right" data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
      <ul class="ui-grid-solo">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
          <a class="voNavigationItem ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_1">Regresar a Menú Principal</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ehm... why don't you just assign a specific class to the element itself? :)
Selecting by id ... you can do that but then again we don't do that. It is just bad practice.

Comment: Your question is missing a set goal. What do you try to achieve here? What is the outcome? (Reply to the comment above: That is just what I was thinking about). Please include edge cases and the like. E.g. the "autogenerated" keyword is quite important to this question then. Because you cannot just do the obvious.

Comment: I need to change the CSS Style for specific anchor, but I can't set any class in HTML side.

Comment: Can you influence the generated code or not?

Comment: I made you a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just like you wrote it...

You can probably skip few things in between, depends on live usage code.

```
#main .ui-footer.ui-bar-inherit.ui-footer-fixed.slideup div:first-of-type ul:first-of-type .ui-block-a a{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```css
#main .ui-footer.ui-bar-inherit.ui-footer-fixed.slideup div:first-of-type ul:first-of-type .ui-block-a a{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-url="..." data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-footer-fixed ui-page-active" style="padding-top: 42px; padding-bottom: 35px; min-height: 735px;">
  <div data-id="navHeaderDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1 id="cxpTitleH1" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div class="voOutput" id="titlePrompt" />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="groupDiv" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-first-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Misin">Misión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Visin">Visión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-last-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_NuestrasSedes">Nuestras Sedes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="navFooterDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo" class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit ui-footer-fixed slideup">
    <div data-iconpos="right" data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
      <ul class="ui-grid-solo">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
          <a class="voNavigationItem ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_1">Regresar a Menú Principal</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @F.Müller "You can probably skip few things in between, depends on live usage code." And is what is asked for. Its example of OP's exact requirement.

Comment: Well idk. You are not wrong. But if my customer asks something I don't give him the "it's what he wanted" when I know better for sure. Well. The question was a bit open.

Comment: @F.Müller I agree. But short anwser was already posted. And I Liked how OP was aware of exact path to wanted element. So i wanted to show specific  CSS usage of that path, so he can learn something from it also.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip a lot of classes

```css
#main .ui-block-a a {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-url="..." data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-footer-fixed ui-page-active" style="padding-top: 42px; padding-bottom: 35px; min-height: 735px;">
  <div data-id="navHeaderDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1 id="cxpTitleH1" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div class="voOutput" id="titlePrompt" />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="groupDiv" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-first-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Misin">Misión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Visin">Visión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-last-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_NuestrasSedes">Nuestras Sedes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="navFooterDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo" class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit ui-footer-fixed slideup">
    <div data-iconpos="right" data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
      <ul class="ui-grid-solo">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
          <a class="voNavigationItem ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_1">Regresar a Menú Principal</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I fear is that I will change some links from other pages that I do not want to change ... but thank you very much!

Comment: @Anita You have an ID selector in the top which means that you change the design only inside that. The id SHOULD be unique in your page which means that you wont change anything else just make sure that the css is loaded only on the page where you want it to load.

Comment: And first posted. SO can be cruel sometimes. Hsve an up vote :)

Comment: Appreciated:) …

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned. It really depends whether you can actually influence the outcome of your html-generator or not.

If you can then just adding a specific class would probably be the way to go. Otherwise, I advise you to use classes instead of ids for the styling.

You only have to be as specific as it is required for the style to work. If one style is more specific than the other style it will be overridden. Selectors such as `+` or `>` etc. add more "power" to the rule. Most of the time it is enough to only combine a few selectors to reach your goal.

The thing is also: You don't want to rely on your html-structure too much in order to have a decent styling. In fact, with classes, you can use pretty much all elements in any order.

```css
.ui-block-a a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-url="..." data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-footer-fixed ui-page-active" style="padding-top: 42px; padding-bottom: 35px; min-height: 735px;">
  <div data-id="navHeaderDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1 id="cxpTitleH1" class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div class="voOutput" id="titlePrompt" />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="groupDiv" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-first-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Misin">Misión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_Visin">Visión</a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all voMenuItem ui-last-child" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_NuestrasSedes">Nuestras Sedes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-id="navFooterDiv" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo" class="ui-footer ui-bar-inherit ui-footer-fixed slideup">
    <div data-iconpos="right" data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar" role="navigation">
      <ul class="ui-grid-solo">
        <li class="ui-block-a">
          <a class="voNavigationItem ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" href="..." id="menu_11InfoGeneral_1">Regresar a Menú Principal</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```